# MongoDB nested value query

Tags: mongodb

I have an entry in my database that looks like:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e93ace3f8208ca743000004"),
  "title" : "Entry",
  "domain" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("4e9305d5f8208cab43000001"),
    "name" : "Google"
  }
}
```

To query for that particular entry (or entries that use the same domain) it *looks* like I'm supposed to query using:

```
db.entries.find({domain._id : ObjectId("4e9305d5f8208cab43000001")})
```

This however produces an error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):1
```

What am I doing wrong in my query? Secondarily, how can I branch this out to PHP?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will need to have the field name in quotes, eg:

```
db.entries.find({ "domain._id" : ... })
```